# How to write from Java to the Windows Event Log?

Tags: java, windows, logging, event-log

How can I write from Java to the Windows Event Log?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**EDIT (2023)**: See JNA https://stackoverflow.com/a/3815771/3937

#### Old answer

Log4J is a Java-based logging utility.  The class `NTEventLogAppender` can be used to "append to the NT event log system". See the documentation here:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/nt/NTEventLogAppender.html

**Edit:** There is a newer version,  [Log4j 2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) "that provides significant improvements over its predecessor."

Comment: Log4J is a good choice because your code doesn't get coupled to the underlying logging target and its easily configured through XML.

Comment: The big problem with NTEventLogAppender is that it requires a native DLL to be placed in all kinds of places you don't want it in.

Comment: It appears to not be available in log4j2 and i don't think there's a replacement.

Comment: In 2023, it appears that this answer is best (JNA): https://stackoverflow.com/a/3815771/3937

Answer (score 10):

You can use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) to write to the Event Log directly without the need of any native DLLs. See Advapi32 and Advapi32Util classes for various event log methods (ships since JNA 3.2.8).

If you're using Log4j, consider [Log4jna](https://github.com/dblock/log4jna) instead of NTEventLogAppender.

Comment: Log4jna has been moved to [GITHUB](https://github.com/dblock/log4jna), in case the link above stop working.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the eventcreate command on Windows XP Pro and above.

```
String command = "eventcreate "
               + " /l APPLICATION"
               + " /so \"" + applicationObjectName + "\""
               + " /t " + lvl
               + " /id " + id
               + " /d \"" + description + "\"";

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

For XP home and lower, you could create a vbs application that writes using the wscript.shell.eventcreate method. However you sacrifice the ability to specify source.

Example:
http://www.ozzu.com/mswindows-forum/posting-event-log-with-batch-files-t76791.html

Comment: how to define applicationObjectName , lvl, etc

Answer (score 5):

Back in 2001 JavaWorld published an article on how to [write messages to the Windows NT Event Log.](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2001/jw-0928-ntmessages.html) Or, you can take a look at the Log4j [NTEventLogAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/nt/NTEventLogAppender.html) class.