# How to log the Java application logs to Windows Event viewer?

Tags: java

I have a Java application in which I want to write unhandled events to the windows event viewer.  Can any one please suggest how to do it?  It would be great if sample code is provided.

Thanks in advance

vinod

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164879/how-to-write-from-java-to-the-windows-event-log

Comment: "it would be great if sample code is provided."  It would be great if you: 1) Found your shift key, and applied it once at the start of every sentence 2) Searched the forum for answers, if none found 3) Ask a *specific* question, showing what you have already achieved through research, and describing exactly where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

log4j

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/nt/NTEventLogAppender.html

Comment: thanks a lot. can you please share some examples on the same.